# JavaScript - Slicing does not work even though I have the right index

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a command that would replace a vowel by another. Here is what I have so far:

```
function trouverEtRemplacerChar(truc, liste, proba) {
    let indexCorrespondances = []
    if (Math.random() <= proba) {
            for (let x = 0 ; x < truc.length; x++) {
                if (liste.indexOf(truc[x].toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                    indexCorrespondances.push(x)
                }
            }
            const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (indexCorrespondances.length))
            if (liste.includes(truc[indexCorrespondances[index]])) {
                indexASupp = liste.indexOf(truc[indexCorrespondances[index]])
                help = liste[indexASupp]
                console.log(liste, indexASupp)
                liste.slice(indexASupp, 1)
                console.log(liste)
                }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code relies on a bit of randomness. What I'm trying to do in the last part is to remove the chosen vowel from the list of possible vowel, as not to have the same word back. It works most of the time, here is the command I run

`console.log("magiquement", ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"], 1)`

Sometimes, I end up getting the same vowel because the two `console.log` show me that the program gets the right index, but does not slice the list as I get the same twice. Any idea as to why that would happen?

Comment: Seems like you supposed to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) not [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) because `slice` doesn't mutate inital array but `splice` do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.slice()` returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array.  It does not modify the original array.  See doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).  So this statement `liste.slice(indexASupp, 1)` doesn't actually do anything by itself since you don't even use its return value.  It does not modify the `liste` array.

You can use `.splice()` instead if you want to modify the original array such as `liste.splice(indexASupp, 1)`.

Comment: THANK YOU, I'm a beginner in Js and completely missed that line even though I feel like I've read the page ten times. 

Comment: @Aza - This is a common mistake with arrays as some methods modify the array like `.push()` or `.sort()` or `.splice()` and some do not like `.slice()` or `.flat()`.